# intent.getExtra returns null while passing data from activity to BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("Test","Test Intent");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+2000,pendingIntent);
```

In BroadcastReceiver onReceive()

```
   String test=intent.getStringExtra("Test");
```

Intent.getExtra returns null while passing data from activity to BroadcastReceiver? Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do it - specify a flag !

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, uniqueRequestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```